# rowIndex is returning -1

Tags: javascript, dom, tablerow

I am using greasemonkey script and have updating the table using following code. I have attached the image of the table. But when I click on the delete , rowIndex returns -1 for all the rows. I am not getting why it is returning -1.

```
table = document.getElementById( 'keys-table' );
if ( !table ) return;
table.innerHTML = '';


// header
row = document.createElement( 'tr' );
th = document.createElement( 'th' );
th.innerHTML = "Group"; row.appendChild( th );
th = document.createElement( 'th' );
th.innerHTML = "Key"; row.appendChild( th );
th = document.createElement( 'th' );
th.innerHTML = "&nbsp;"; row.appendChild( th );
table.appendChild( row );

// keys
for ( i = 0 ; i < keys.length ; i++ ) {
    row = document.createElement( 'tr' );
    td = document.createElement( 'td' );
    td.innerHTML = keys[i][0];
    row.appendChild( td );
    td = document.createElement( 'td' );
    td.innerHTML = keys[i][1];
    row.appendChild( td );
    td = document.createElement( 'td' );

    button = document.createElement( 'input' );
    button.type = 'button';
    button.value = 'Delete';
    button.addEventListener( "click", function(event) {
            DeleteKey( event.target.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex,event.target);
        }, false );
    td.appendChild( button );
    row.appendChild( td );

    table.appendChild( row );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tr` elements want to be in a `<tbody>` element.

Usually the browser inserts one automatically, but if it did, you're wiping it out with...

```
table.innerHTML = '';
```

If you make sure that the original table has a `<tbody>`, then do this...

```
table = document.getElementById( 'keys-table' );
if ( !table ) return;

var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
tbody.innerHTML = '';
```

...and then append the rows to `tbody`, it will work.

---

Side note, but I'd personally recommend using DOM methods to remove the old rows instead of `innerHTML`.

```
var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
while( tbody.firstChild )
    tbody.removeChild( tbody.firstChild );
```

or

```
var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
while( tbody.rows[0] )
    tbody.deleteRow( tbody.rows[0] );
```

Seems more proper.

Answer (score 2):

Good question, and the answer of "am not I am" is correct, make sure to append a tbody to your table and then append your rows to this tbody.